# AWS Glue - custom s3 partition to single table

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have multiple files stored into an S3 bucket under uniquely named folders which I would expect AWS Glue to put into a single table - instead it creates one per file. Any ideas how to configure the crawler to get a single table ?

The current tS3 structure is s3://bucket_name/YYYYMMDDUUID/data.json:

- 20210801123123cfec/data.json
- 20210808876551cedc/data.json
  ....
- 20210810112313feed/data.json

The json schema is definitely not a problem, it is similar - for example when I change the folder names from the custom names to "1", "2", ... etc I get a single table with multiple partitions.

Comment: How will you be using the table? If you're just going to use it in Amazon Athena, then you could cheat a bit and just get it to create the schema for one folder. Then, use that schema definition to point to the top-level folder. Athena will automatically look through all subdirectories for files.

Comment: that works perfectly, thanks @JohnRotenstein. 
One more question: is there a way to filter out files that do not match the schema ? For example 20210801123123cfec also has foo.csv, foo.log, etc in it and Athena queries break with "Invalid Json" (excluding using "where path not like" does not work)

Comment: I am not aware of a way to tell the AWS Glue crawler, or Amazon Athena, to only look at a subset of files.